# How can I add a checkbox to a table that reads and writes the object property that it represents in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox, tableview, tablecell

I have a table that lists objects of type `Bot` which have a name and `isOn` properties that I want to list:

```
private SimpleStringProperty name;
private boolean isOn;
```

The boolean isOn, I want to be read from a checkbox and also editable from that checkbox

So far, I have been able to add a checkbox to a column in my table for each row but it is purely visual (i.e. it is not tied to the `Bot`'s `isOn` member).

How can I make the checkbox read and write from and to this member of `Bot`?

Here is my code dealing with the Table altogether:

```
ObservableList<Bot> bots = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private TableView<Bot> botTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Bot, String> nameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Bot, Boolean> statusColumn;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Bot, String>("name"));
    statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Bot, Boolean>("on"));
    statusColumn.setSortable(false);

    statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Bot, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>(){
        @Override public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Bot, Boolean> features) {
            return new SimpleBooleanProperty(features.getValue() != null);
        }
    });

    // create a cell value factory with an add button for each row in the table.
    statusColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Bot, Boolean>, TableCell<Bot, Boolean>>() {
        @Override public TableCell<Bot, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Bot, Boolean> personBooleanTableColumn) {
            return new AddBotCell(/*stage, botTable*/);
        }
    });

    botTable.setItems(bots);
}

/** A table cell containing a button for adding a new person. */
private class AddBotCell extends TableCell<Bot, Boolean> {
    // a checkbox for adding a new bot.
    final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
    // pads and centers the add button in the cell.
    final StackPane paddedCheckBox = new StackPane();

    AddBotCell(/*final Stage stage, final TableView table*/) {
        paddedCheckBox.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        paddedCheckBox.getChildren().add(checkbox);
        checkbox.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            }
        });
    }
    /** places an add checkbox in the row only if the row is not empty. */
    @Override protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setGraphic(checkbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the checkbox, if the cell becomes empty. Furthermore you need to update the value when the user interacts with the `CheckBox`. This is better done from a listener to the `selected` property:

```
private class AddBotCell extends TableCell<Bot, Boolean> {
    // a button for adding a new person.
    final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
    // pads and centers the add button in the cell.
    final StackPane paddedCheckBox = new StackPane();
    // records the y pos of the last button press so that the add person dialog can be shown next to the cell.
    final DoubleProperty buttonY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private boolean updating = false;

    AddBotCell(/*final Stage stage, final TableView table*/) {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        paddedCheckBox.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        paddedCheckBox.getChildren().add(checkbox);
        checkbox.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!updating) {
                updating = true;
                ((Bot)getTableRow().getItem()).setIsOn(newValue);
                updating = false;
            }
        });
    }

    /** places an add button in the row only if the row is not empty. */
    @Override protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(paddedCheckBox);
            updating = true;
            checkbox.setSelected(item);
            updating = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also your `cellValueFactory` should use the value of the property.

```
statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Bot, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>(){
    @Override public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Bot, Boolean> features) {
        return new SimpleBooleanProperty(features.getValue().isIsOn());
    }
});
```

Comment: what's wrong with using CheckBoxTableCell (vs. rolling your own)?

Comment: Also, I cannot retrieve the Bot object from getTableRow().getItem() as it won't let me call the setIsOn(newValue) function.

Comment: I forgot the method name and the item needs to be cast since for some reason JavaFX uses the raw type for the `TableRow` of a cell... Edited the code. Should work now...

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain what the purpose of the updating boolean is? What bug exactly is it preventing from happening?

Comment: @LucaGuarro If you choose to store the `BooleanProperty` as field in the `Bot` class, using `setIsOn()` would update the item which would trigger an unnecessary update. Also you don't need to handle updates of the `selected` state if it's done during an update of the item.

Comment: Oh okay I see. So instead of a primitive boolean, if I gave the Bot a BooleanProperty as a member and set it to checkbox.selectedProperty(), wherever I were to change that BooleanProperty in the code, it would be reflected in the checkbox?

Comment: @LucaGuarro provided you return the property from the `cellValueFactory`, yes.